# Difference between lambda and properties population?

Tags: c#, lambda

A library that I use (`Mvc.Mailer`) makes us write code such as

```
return Populate(x =>
{
    x.ViewName = "Welcome";
    recipients.ForEach(r => x.To.Add(r));
});
```

I started wondering if it was simply a design choice or if the lambda version above has better functionality/performance than the following code ?

```
var populatedObject = new ObjectToPopulate();

populatedObject.ViewName = "Welcome";
recipients.ForEach(r => populatedObject.To.Add(r));

return populatedObject;
```

Is the difference purely syntactical or does it go beyond a simple writing preference ?

Comment: AFAIK it's just preference, both of the ways will create an object and populate, but i feel the first one may be a bit quicker, due to memory references ect.

Comment: When considering performance you should use a profiler and measure the exact difference as it will highly depend on your local environment (CPU, memory, ...).Apart from this your question is not solvable to us as we don´t know what `Populate` does. I assume it will wrap the delegate and add some more behaviour which in your second example won´t execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no difference if the `Populate` function just invoked the lambda expression - it would be just a matter of convenience/syntax.

Looking at your particular example - `Mvc.Mailer` seems to have some additional plumbing inside `Populate` (namely the `PopulateBody` method), so in your case the result could be different.

Comment: After asking the question I decompiled the populate method and found that a lot more than simple assignation was happening, maybe I should not have given a precise example of library to avoid this problem. Thank you for your answer.